# How do I skip over a String?

Tags: java

This method prints out a text representation of a square or rectangle depending on what lengths the user enters. It prints out the correct dimensions however, how would I make it hollow?

```
public String printShape() {
    String message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            message += "* ";
        message += "\n";
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Think about what the coordinates are when a star should be printed, and print a space for all others.

Comment: length, width - what are they to the method ?

Comment: how would I make it hollow? means

Answer (score 0):

You want to print a star when either you're at a boundary. Use an if statement to detect this and print a star. Otherwise, print a space.

```
public String printShape() {
    String message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            message += i == 0 || i == j ? "* " : "  ";
        message += "\n";
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: That gives me an error that states: The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean

Comment: I had "i = 0 || i = j" but ninja fixed it. Did you copy it before that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend passing your values in as parameters instead of pulling them from a global scope.

```
public String printShape(int width, int length) {
    String message = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        message += "*";
    }
    message += "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        message += "*";
        for (int j = 0; j < (width -2); j++) {
            message += "*";
        }
        message += "*\n";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        message += "*";
    }
    message += "\n";
    return message;
}
```